# Stability of extended enolates

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, stability, regioselectivity

I'd expect an extended enolate to be more stable than a normal enolate, when both can form, but my textbook suggests otherwise.

What is the stability of an extended enolate compared with a normal enolate? For example, following an enolate alkylation of the molecule depicted below, which product ($\alpha$- or $\gamma$-alkylated) will form?

> [image]

Comment: It might be beneficial if you could provide a reference to your textbook.

Comment: It probably depends on the deprotonation conditions

Comment: @orthocresol Thanks! But could you please elaborate? Do you mean bulkiness of the base? How could you favour one product over the other?

Comment: I was looking for a post, because it has been discussed here before, and I found it: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/43024/16683

Comment: @orthocresol Thanks a lot! The answer makes sense, but it doesn’t explain why alpha-deprotonation is kinetically favoured. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: With LDA for example you can form a six-membered TS (Ireland model) with a $\ce{C=O...Li}$ interaction. I've heard that the model is a simplification of the truth, but the bottom line is that there's probably some kind of involvement of the carbonyl group.

Comment: Yes, it’s almost a Duplikate of that question except one is about cyclic compounds the other about linear ones …